# Closing and restarting project on rebuild

Tags: c#, visual-studio, blazor

I am running a `client` and a `server` project with blazor and everytime i hit `CTRL`+`F5` i first have to manually close the running processes.
Is there  a way to automatically close the current running instnaces and restart them anew after build when i hit the combo ?

Comment: Does it not automatically rebuild on file save for you?

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: Hmm, strange.  It does for me.  You can even see it in the `Output` log (for me) rebuiding the project.